# Return Soql result to a field

Tags: soql

I'm need to return the result of a SOQL query to a field.

My object is called Metric. I have a field called SOQL which houses the SOQL query and I have a field called Result. My Query is below, How Do I get the result of my query to populate in the result field?

`SELECT SUM (Number_A__c) FROM Account where Number_A__c !=null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
List<AggregateResult> res = [SELECT SUM(Number_A__c) sum FROM Account WHERE Number_A__c != NULL];

Decimal metrics = null;
if (!res.isEmpty()) {
    metrics = (Decimal) res[0].get('sum');
}

System.debug(metrics);
```

Useful links:

[Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

Comment: Since you answered, you should show the query being taken from the SOQL__c field on Metric__c like the OP explained. However, there is a lot of missing information, such as when does the OP want the values calculated, how they will make it scale etc. NB: I voted to close because the OP showed no effort in research.

Comment: @PhilW I have updated the answer, but that was the point to show it on different object: so lyslexic could read the article and apply the same approach to their case. I have also voted to close the question.

Comment: The article link doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Added one extra https://, fixed now. @PhilW